# Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process - React Native - Local Notification

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-push-notification

(Before you mark this question as duplicate, please read the whole question)

I am using [react-native-push-notification](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-push-notification) library in my React-Native Application.

In my app I have not initialized Firebase because I do not need any remote notifications as of now. Currently I am scheduling a local notification and when the notification comes I am expecting user actions from it. Based on the button pressed I want to make appropriate API calls.

So to achieve this I used PushNotification.configure method, but it is throwing me **"Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process. Make sure Firebase is initialised"** error.

I am being forced to use Firebase, when I have absolutely no need of it.

Could someone please help me out here, I have been searching for answer from past 2 days. I am quite new to React Native and I am still learning it. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 29):

Finally I found the solution, it was actually in the documentation itself but I somehow over looked.
I will post it here because I am sure there's someone like me out there.

We are supposed to add `requestPermissions: Platform.OS === 'ios',` in `PushNotification.configure` like this:

```
PushNotification.configure({
    onNotification: function (notification) {
      console.log('LOCAL NOTIFICATION ==>', notification);
    },

    // This line solves the problem that I was facing.
    requestPermissions: Platform.OS === 'ios',
  });
```

Comment: Geat, saved lots of effort ;)

Comment: How to request permissions then

Comment: This no longer works when Android API version is 33 or higher.

Comment: Removing this as accepted answer as this solution no longer works.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer no longer works when using Android API version ≥ 33.

---

### Problem

The problem is that by setting

```js
requestPermissions: Platform.OS === 'ios'
```

permissions will never be requested, and changing it to `true` or running `PushNotification.requestPermissions()` manually will always throw the **"Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process. Make sure Firebase is initialized."** error.

The only workaround is to have users go into app settings and toggle the notification permission manually.

Unfortunately, as [react-native-push-notification](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification) hasn't been updated since 2021 and appears abandoned, it can no longer be used for local notifications without Firebase support on latest Android versions.

---

### Solution

Use [@notifee/react-native](https://github.com/invertase/notifee)